# joomla templating custom JDOC statements

Tags: joomla, template-engine

Which Joomla Platform / CMS class should I extend in order to make my own custom JDOC:include tags?

I would like to have custom JDOC tags like

```
<JDOC:include type="scripts" />
<JDOC:include type="scripts-body" />
```

and a bunch of other types.

Comment: And what type of functionality you want to implement here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new file at below location to add custom jdoc tag..

```
libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/
```

File name should be same as the tag you are adding.. suppose you want to use `scripts` as tag then file name should be `scripts.php`

Now in this file you need to add below code. as tag name is `scripts` so class name should be `JDocumentRendererScripts`

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

class JDocumentRendererScripts extends JDocumentRenderer
{
    public function render($scripts, $params = array(), $content = null)
    {
        $contents  = "";
        //Do your work here
        return $contents;

    }


}
?>
```

Now you can use custom jdoc code `<JDOC:include type="scripts" />`

Hope this helps..